# Getting the absolute path from a relative path

Tags: c, path, filepath

I know this question has been asked before ( the answer being `realpath()` ), but my requirements are a little bit different. `realpath()` is a non-standard function. I need an ANSI compliant function to return the full-path form a relative path. The function it's self does not have to be part of `c89`, but the code must be 100% `c89` compliant.

Thank You for any help.

**EDIT:** Should have put for UNIX-Like systems. I don't really care about windows at this point.

Comment: The problem is that the definition of an absolute path depends on the OS. So there cannot be a portable solution (at least not without a bunch of #ifdefs, or runtime checks based on the OS).

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll update my question for UNIX systems

Comment: @Ankush: If you're on a Unix(-like) system, then you're already POSIX, and should already have `realpath()`. Why would you like strict ANSI/ISO compliance then, if your program will be POSIX-specific anyways?

Comment: @KemyLand Under `glibc`, you need to enable (via a #define) support for `GNU_EXTENSIONS` Which may be POSIX compliant, but it is not the same as confirming to the `c89` standard.

As for the second part of your comment: I sort of prefer keeping all code I write strict ANSI, and anyways in this case it's not my choice

Comment: @Ankush: What do you mean? POSIX is a very respectable standard. I mean, every OS out there implements it... except for Microsoft Crapware(R) of course. ANSI/ISO C is *way* too much portable. It is intended to work even on the smallest of embedded systems! It even defines a "freestanding" mode if the standard library is not enoughly portable for you. On the other hand, if you need even the least of OS services, you need an OS API, no? POSIX is the ultimate Unix API, and so, if you need Unix services, such as `realpath()`, you need POSIX.

Comment: @Ankush: If you *can't* use POSIX (you just edited your comment and said that you can't chose), then how whoever-made-you-do-this thinks this can be done without work from a Unix kernel?

Comment: @KemyLand My task requires I do not use any extensions to the language, and `realpath()` is just that. It's not that I can't use POSIX functions completely, I just can not use any extensions to the standard, weather they are POSIX compliant or not doesn't matter. I didn't come up with the task, I just want to learn and find an answer.

Comment: What a crappy assignment.

Comment: But if you are not allowed to use POSIX, why would you need to know your path? Also other functions for using paths like `chdir` are part of the POSIX standard and not included in ANSI C.

Comment: But `chdir()` does not require any **GNU Extensions** the use of `realpath()` (at least on my system) **requires** me to use GNU_EXTENSIONS. The GNU_EXTENSIONS are also needed when using inline functions and the sort. That is what I need to avoid - the use of extensions and `realpath()` requires a GNU extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the C Language Standards define functions to deal with directories or paths.  You cannot complete your goal without some knowledge of the operating system and come OS specific system calls or library functions.

You specify that your program is targeting the Unix operating system.  There are hundreds of flavors of Unix (see http://www.levenez.com/unix/  and this 34 page timeline: http://www.levenez.com/unix/unix_a4.pdf ).  The most portable way to deal with directories for a unix target is to use Posix standardized system calls.

Posix is not an extension to the language, it is a specification for operating system structures and interfaces.  It is implemented in standard header files and libraries.  Your program can adhere to the c89, c90, c99 or c11 standards and use Posix system calls. `gcc` will enable the Posix part of the glibc on Posix systems unless you instruct it to restrict support to the Standard C library.

Posix standardized `realpath` in 2001, it is available on just about every current unix-like system. if you cannot use this, you are going to rewrite its functionality with `getcwd()`, `stat()`, `readlink()`, and other system calls and your code will be less portable.

The manual page is here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html

**EDIT**: There is a contorted solution that does not use explicit Posix support, but implicitly relies on the availability of a Posix shell.  It is not a recommended solution for production code, but it might fit your specific constraints.  Here are the steps:

- with `strrchr`, extract the initial path part of the filename.
- create a command the changes the current directory to that and prints the current directory to a temporary file
- open and read the contents of that temporary file.
- remove the temporary file.
- concatenate the path and the filename with a `/` separator

Note that changing the current directory in a sub-shell will not impact your program's own current directory.

**EDIT**: Implementing the above is a bit tricky.  You need to handle some special cases.  Here is an example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *my_realpath(const char *path) {
    const char *lastsep, *fname;
    char *cmd, *dir, *newdir;
    int pathlen, fnamelen, rc, size, pos, len;
    char buf[256];
    char tmpfile[L_tmpnam];
    FILE *fp;

    if (!tmpnam(tmpfile))
        return NULL;

    pathlen = 0;
    lastsep = strrchr(path, '/');
    if (lastsep) {
        pathlen = lastsep - path;
        if (pathlen == 0) {
            /* special case the root directory */
            pathlen = 1;
        }
    }
    fname = path + pathlen;
    fnamelen = strlen(fname);
    if (!strcmp(fname, ".")
    ||  !strcmp(fname, "/.")
    ||  !strcmp(fname, "..")
    ||  !strcmp(fname, "/..")) {
        pathlen += fnamelen;
        fname += fnamelen;
        fnamelen = 0;
    }
    if (*fname == '/') {
        fname++;
        fnamelen--;
    }
    if (pathlen > 0) {
        size = strlen("cd ") + pathlen + strlen("; pwd > ") + strlen(tmpfile) + 1;
        cmd = malloc(size);
        if (!cmd)
            return NULL;
        sprintf(cmd, "cd %.*s; pwd > %s", pathlen, path, tmpfile);
    } else {
        size = strlen("pwd > ") + strlen(tmpfile) + 1;
        cmd = malloc(size);
        if (!cmd)
            return NULL;
        sprintf(cmd, "pwd > %s", tmpfile);
    }
    rc = system(cmd);
    free(cmd);
    if (rc != 0)
        return NULL;

    fp = fopen(tmpfile, "r");
    size = pos = 0;
    dir = NULL;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        len = strcspn(buf, "\n");
        size += len + 1;
        newdir = realloc(dir, size + fnamelen + 1);
        if (!newdir) {
            free(dir);
            dir = NULL;
            break;
        }
        dir = newdir;
        memcpy(dir + pos, buf, len);
        pos += len;
        dir[pos] = '\0';
        if (buf[len] == '\n')
            break;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    remove(tmpfile);
    if (dir != NULL) {
        if (pos > 0 && dir[pos - 1] != '/' && fnamelen > 0) {
            dir[pos++] = '/';
        }
        strcpy(dir + pos, fname);
    }
    return dir;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    char *absolute_path;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        errno = 0;
        absolute_path = my_realpath(argv[i]);
        if (absolute_path == NULL) {
            printf("my_realpath(\"%s\") -> NULL: %s\n", argv[i], strerror(errno));
        } else {
            printf("my_realpath(\"%s\") -> \"%s\"\n", argv[i], absolute_path);
            free(absolute_path);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer! Just wondering if `-std=c89` or `-ansi` on my compiler flags would count as restricting support to the c std library?

Comment: Also I was just wondering if `realpath()` is not an extension to the language, why does it require me to use the `-D` flag during compile time, or use `#define GNU_SOURCE`. It's just a little confusing to me

Comment: There is a distinction between language extensions such as gnu cc's `typeof` operator and a specific target environment for which some compiler configuration may be necessary.

Comment: And the `-std-c89`? Is that restricting the c standard Library?

Comment: @Ankush: Yes, I'm afraid `gcc -std=c89` restricts both the supported language and the default library  support.

Comment: At least on my system (Slackware 13.1 with gcc 4.4.4),  `-ansi`, `-std=c89` and even `-std=c99` all give a warning about realpath not being declared at compilation. However, despite this warning the program still links fine and works as expected.

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist: these options disable the déclarations for types and functions in the standard headers that are not specified in the corresponding C Standard. They do notre change the librairies, so the link still fonds `realpath`.